# Bootstrap radio inline input columns and wrap text

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

How can I get bootstrap to equal align my radio form to have my question and three answers split into 4 columns like col-sm-3. I want it to wrap the text in each column when its too long. example form below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Form control: inline radio buttons</h2>
  <p>The form below contains three inline radio buttons:</p>
  <form class="form-check-inline">
    <label class="control-label">This is some question: </label>
    <label class="form-check-label">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="optradio" checked>Option 1 which is really long and spans most of the page compared to the other options
    </label>
    <label class="form-check-label">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="optradio">Option 2 is a small option
    </label>
    <label class="form-check-label">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="optradio">Option 3 is another long option which i would prefer was wordwrapped and options divided equally over the width
    </label>
  </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I would like the check box to be split into columns and wrap the input text

```
Form control: inline radio buttons
The form below contains three inline radio buttons:

This is some question: | Option 1 which is really long       | Option 2 is a small | option Option 3 is another long option which
                       | and spans most of the page compared |                     | i would prefer was wordwrapped and options 
                       | to the other options                |                     | divided equally over
```

the `|` char here i have added just to indicate columns, i dont expect them to actually be present in the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using the container-row-column classes correctly -- `<div class="container"><div class="row"><div class="col-xs-12">...` Refer to [Bootstrap 3.4.1 documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/#overview) for more information.

Additionally, the latest Bootstrap version is 4.6 with 5.0 in public beta, consider updating your Boostrap version.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <h2>Form control: inline radio buttons</h2>
      <p>The form below contains three inline radio buttons:</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <form class="form-check-inline row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <label class="control-label">This is some question:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <label class="form-check-label"><input checked class="form-check-input" name="optradio" type="radio">Option 1 which is really long and spans most of the page compared to the other options</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <label class="form-check-label"><input class="form-check-input" name="optradio" type="radio">Option 2 is a small option</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <label class="form-check-label"><input class="form-check-input" name="optradio" type="radio">Option 3 is another long option which i would prefer was wordwrapped and options divided equally over the width</label>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ah ok thanks, I wasnt sure if the good practice was to just wrap each element in the standard row/col layout or if there was a way within the form classes to add its colum width like you do with col for divs in row.

Comment: You shouldn't do `<label class="form-check-label col-xs-3">` since labels aren't always parent elements in forms -- for instance, in 4.6, input labels are `<div class="form-group"><label>labelname</label><input></div>`

Comment: Thanks, trying to work out why it doesnt work with my head section but does with yours

Comment: I am using link `cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css` and script `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js`

Comment: Possibly closed early/unclosed divs? Bootstrap breaks pretty spectacularly on those. Also, try using a code indenter like https://www.10bestdesign.com/dirtymarkup/ -- can't help much without updated code